# $f(x)=x^3-ax^2-ax+1,\;\;|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|=3$

Tags: roots, solution-verification, elementary-functions

> Find all $a\in \mathbb R$ such that the zero-points of the function
>   $$f(x)=x^3-ax^2-ax+1$$ Satisfy the equation: $$|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|=3$$

My work:

$$
\begin{split}
f(x) &= x^3-ax^2-ax+1 \\
     &= x^3+1-ax(x+1)\\
     &= (x+1)(x^2-x+1-ax) \\
     &=(x+1)(x^2-(a+1)x+1) \\
x_1  &= -1
\end{split}
$$

By Viéta's formulae:
$$
\begin{split}
x_2 +     x_3 &= a+1 \\
x_2 \cdot x_3 &= 1\implies x_2\;\&\;x_3>0 \lor x_2\;\&\;x_3<0\\
a &= 1\implies x_2=x_3=-1 \leftarrow \Delta=0 \\
&\text{square of a binomial, double solution}
\end{split}
$$

$$$$

Then it really is:

for $x_1=x_2=x_3=-1$
$$|x_1|+|x_2|+|x_3|=3$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What about $a=-3$? This is obtained, in the case $x_2,x_3<0$, by changing $x$ for $-x$, which changes the sign of the roots $x_2,x_3$. So, $-x_2-x_3=|x_2|+|x_3|=2$ tells us that $a+1=-2$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy Thank you! Then I have a square of a binomial, too. And merry Christmas if you celebrate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ x_1 = -1 $, we have 
$$ |x_2| + |x_3| = 2 $$
now, if $ x_2, x_3 $ real Number
can be four solution.

- $ x_2 > 0, x_3 > 0 $

$x_2 + x_3 = a+1$

$a =1$

- $ x_2 < 0, x_3 < 0 $

$x_2 + x_3 = -(a+1)$

$a =-3$

- $ x_2 < 0, x_3 > 0 $ or $ x_2 > 0, x_3 < 0 $

$ x_2 - x_3 = +- \sqrt{(a+1)^2 - 4} $
If $x_2 = x_3$
So,

$ (a+1)^2 - 4 = 0 $

$ a = -3 or a = 1$

if not ? $ a < -3 or a > 1$

Comment: From $x_1=-1$ you get that $|x_1|=1$. This implies that $|x_2|+|x_3|=2$, not $4$.